# Picasso, image not shown

Tags: android, picasso, infowindow

I am using a Class that implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter.

I want to show an image loaded from internet inside the info window:

```
 @Override
    public View getInfoContents(final Marker m) {
        //Carga layout personalizado.
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.info_windows_origen, null);
        String info = m.getTitle();
        String direccion = m.getSnippet();

        String url = m.getSnippet();
        ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.info_window_nombre)).setText("PUNTO DE PARTIDA");
        ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.info_window_placas)).setText(info);
        ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.info_window_estado)).setText(direccion);
        ImageView imgProfile =(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.info_window_imagen);

        SharedPreferences prefs =
                getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(MISDATOS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        String imagen = prefs.getString("imagen", "por_defecto@email.com");

        Log.d("BOTON ORIGEN ","mi imagen "+urlProfileImg+imagen);

        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(urlProfileImg+imagen).fit().into(imgProfile);

        return v;
    }
```

I have checked both, the image URL and the image name, and both are correct, but the image is not shown.

Comment: You can remove `fit()` and have a try .

Comment: Have you given the right permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure you have internet permission in the manifest. 
Try removing fit
Posting the url you are providing would be easier to work with